# populating a form from JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I'm trying to populate a form (onClick) with data from a JSON file.
I can do it succcesfully from an array but when I try to parse the local (same folder as the .html) JSON file it doesn't work.

```
<script>
var marks = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#RQdata").click(function(event) {
        $.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
            $.each(data.markers, function(key, val) {
                marks.push(val[key]);


            });
        });
    });
});

function populateList() {
    for (var i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) {
        var mark = new Option(marks[i].name, markers[i].latlng);
        document.getElementById('locationList').options.add(mark);
    }
}
</script>


<h2>List</h2>
<form name="aForm">
  <select name="locationList" id="locationList" size="6" onChange="alert(value);" style=" width:800px;owerflow: auto;">
  </select>
  <input type="button" id="RQdata" name="Request Data" value="Request Data" >
</form>
```

my test.json

```
{"markers":
            [{"latlng":[55.587,17.044],"name":"Some name 1"},
            {"latlng":[55.577,17.044],"name":"Some name 2"},
            {"latlng":[55.507456,17.617585],"name":"Some name 3"},
            {"latlng":[55.25642,17.154904],"name":"Some name 4"},
            {"latlng":[55.103217,17.07776],"name":"Some name 5"}]}
```

Best regards

Comment: Can you see any error messages in the developer tools of your browser? Some browsers also prevent ajax requests to local files.

Comment: inspect the request in browser console and see if status is 200 and what is returned. Read API to learn how to add ajax error handler also  http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/ Problem could be as simple as incorrect path however you haven't provided much other than it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're several mistakes in your code, and the version below works.

```
var marks = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#RQdata").click(function(event) {
    $.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data.markers, function(key, val) {
        marks.push(val);  //It should be val instead of val[key]
    });

    populateList();  // You didn't call this function here
    });
});
});

function populateList() {
for (var i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) {
    var mark = new Option(marks[i].name, marks[i].latlng);  //marks instead of markers here
    document.getElementById('locationList').options.add(mark);
}
}
```

Please use inspector or something else to debug.

Also, as @matt mentioned in the comment, some browser (like Chrome) will prohibit access to local file by XHR.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Every piece of code I tried I did it in Chrome maybe why it didn't work.
tried your code in firefox and it worked!
is there something to be done so it works in chrome as well?

Comment: Maybe you should put the json on a web server, instead of just put it on local disk.